# Global Variable in php and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [passing variable between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127988/passing-variable-between-pages)

I need to create a variable that I can use in one PHP page to assign a category to this variable. When I've assigned a value, how I can pass that value to another PHP page?

Do I have to use a global variable?

Comment: How is this related to JavaScript? Or do you ask about PHP-generated JS globals?

Comment: because i use a script in js that add a class to a particolar image(in the php file),with that class i give the value at the variable category,so i have to use that variable in another php file... how i can do this?

Comment: Page1.php

<img class="try">

script.js 

`$(".try").click(function(){ 
   if($(this).hasClass("actrive")){
      $(this).removeClass("active"); 
      }else{ 
         $(this).addClass("active"); 
    } 
});
 
 if($(".sp_img1").hasClass(".attivo")){ 
    var cat1= blabla; 
    }); 
}; `

page 2.php 

i have to use that variable cat1 

`if(cat1==blabla){ include page3.php }`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass variables from page to page using:

1. [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).
2. A common config file that is included throughout all of your pages.
3. Forms ([hidden fields](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms07.htm) etc).
4. [Cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Each approach has its own use, so you'll need to choose according to the circumstance. If the variable in question will stay the same throughout your app, I'd suggest placing it in a config file. If its a user-specific variable, I'd suggest using sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Its depend on you what you want to use for passing value from one php page to another.

You can use [Session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php), [Cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) or Forms by using `$_GET` and `$_POST` method:

Example : By using Session

```
//page1.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;

//you can access this in page2.php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

Example : By using Cookies

```
//page1.php
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain);
//you can access it in page2.php like this
echo $_COOKIE["name"];
```

Example : By using `GET` and `POST`

You can use `GET` with `anchor` tag and for `POST` you need form submission.

Read more about GET and POST :

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Hope this information will help you

Comment: yes it helps but i'll post you an example

page1 

<img class="try"></img>


script.js
$(".try").click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("actrive")){
   $(this).removeClass("active");
  }else{
   $(this).addClass("active");
  }
 });

 if($(".sp_img1").hasClass(".attivo")){
  var cat1= blabla;
     });
 };

page 2.php

i have to use that variable cat1

if(cat1==blabla){
include page3.php
}

Comment: Put this code in you post